# Search keyword(s) that matches data in MySQL (on level)

Tags: mysql

Recently I started a project, but now i have a little problem.. I need to make a point system:

When user write a post(like blog post), his post is analyzed by a script( using keyword from database).
The problem is that my keyword have to be on 10 levels.

For ex:
Keyword Level 1 = angry
Keyword Level 2 = be happy

Ok.. when i write :" I'm so angry today" I need to receive level 1(but just in background to use that result for arrange the sentence "I'm so angry today" to his level.

Can somebody help me? (MySql)
Have a nice day!

Comment: Are your ten keywords constant? Or you have `(keyword, level)` map table?

Comment: What level is `I'm angry and can't to be happy`?

Comment: My Keyword are constant in the table Keywords Level 1 i have 10 keywords that match with that level

Comment: My algorithm have bugs and yeah, the question is good, sentence I'm angry and can't to be happy have equal level 1, equal level 2, but that i will fix later